# Not understanding the interaction between cin.get() and while loops

Tags: c++, iostream

So, I'm a absolute beginner in C++ and while going through the books I encounter this example:

```c++
int character;

while ((character = cin.get())!= EOF)
    cout.put(character);
```

So I decided to copy it and test it out in Visual Studio and I encounter this situation:

```
Testing sentence 1
Testing sentence 1
Testing ^z sentence 2
Testing Why is the loop still going?
Why is the loop still going?
^z
```

So in theory the cout.put() function should stop after cin.get() reaches the ctrl-z. However, the loop continues. I even tried having the ctrl-z at the end of the input and it presented similar outcomes, perhaps I'm missing out on some crucial knowledge regarding streams and the interaction with while loops?

Answer (score 0):

On Microsoft Windows, you must press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> <kbd>CTRL-Z</kbd> <kbd>ENTER</kbd> on the console for your program to register end-of-file.

Pressing <kbd>CTRL-Z</kbd> <kbd>ENTER</kbd> in the middle of the line is not sufficient. This only works at the start of the line.

This is not a matter of the C++ language itself, but rather the operating system and maybe also the C++ runtime library that you are using. On other operating systems, such as Linux or MacOS, the behavior is different.